# npm - package existing js code

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm learning about npm modules and I'm trying to package this module as npm package.

I have read the docs on how to create an npm

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules

I understand an export function is required, my question is, should I wrap the following function as an export statement!? :-/

```
/*!
 * fullcalendar-rightclick v1.8
 * Docs & License: https://github.com/mherrmann/fullcalendar-rightclick
 * (c) 2015 Michael Herrmann
 */

(function($) {
    function monkeyPatchViewClass(View) {
        View = View.class || View;
        var renderFn = 'render' in View.prototype ? 'render' : 'renderDates';
        var originalRender = View.prototype[renderFn];
        View.prototype[renderFn] = function() {
            originalRender.call(this);
            if (! this.el.data('fullcalendar-rightclick')) {
                this.registerRightclickListener();
                this.el.data('fullcalendar-rightclick', true)
            }
        };
        View.prototype.registerRightclickListener = function() {
            var that = this;
            this.el.on('contextmenu', function(ev) {
                var eventElt = $(ev.target).closest('.fc-event');
                if (eventElt.length) {
                    var seg = eventElt.data('fc-seg');
                    return that.trigger('eventRightclick', this, seg.event, ev);
                } else {
                    // Users of this library may add custom content inside
                    // FullCalendar's DOM structure, eg. popovers. We don't want
                    // to catch rightclicks on these custom elements, so we
                    // check that the clicked element actually lies inside one
                    // of FullCalendars default containers:
                    var fcContainer = $(ev.target).closest(
                        '.fc-bg, .fc-slats, .fc-content-skeleton, ' +
                        '.fc-bgevent-skeleton, .fc-highlight-skeleton'
                    );
                    if (fcContainer.length) {
                        var cell;
                        if (that.coordMap) {
                            // FullCalendar < 2.5.0:
                            that.coordMap.build();
                            cell = that.coordMap.getCell(ev.pageX, ev.pageY);
                        } else {
                            // FullCalendar >= 2.5.0:
                            that.prepareHits();
                            var hit = that.queryHit(ev.pageX, ev.pageY);
                            cell = that.getHitSpan(hit);
                        }
                        if (cell)
                            return that.trigger(
                                'dayRightclick', null, cell.start, ev
                            );
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    var fc = $.fullCalendar;
    monkeyPatchViewClass(fc.views.agenda);
    monkeyPatchViewClass(fc.views.basic);
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

No you dont need to wrap you module code into a function scope.
The contents of the nodejs module is executed in its own private scope and you use module.exports for exposing its contents to other modules.

You might be interested in reading about [nodejs modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) to learn more.

EDIT:
Just realized you are trying to use a 3rd party library targeting browser environment. What you normally would do if you want to use npm to build browser libraries is to use it together with [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) as part of a build process which would transpile your nodejs modules into browser loadable scripts and insert all necessary baggage for you.